# Ubuntu 12.04 Can't Login-Tty Console said: -bash: /usr/bin/byobu/-launch: no such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, bash, login

I face problem in login to Ubuntu 12.04. I think it's caused by accessing super user (if not wrong). I type `sudo nautilus` to put a background to burg, but i fail x_x. After reboot, i can't login to desktop. But i can login as guest. I had 'googling' for problem solving. Most of it is login to screen like terminal (maybe tty console) by pressing ctrl+alt+F1. But after i login system says:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/byobu/-launch: no such file or directory
```

help help help :(

Answer (score 4):

Looks like byobu has added some broken code to your `.profile` file. Try [booting into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) to get a root shell. Once you're in a root shell, run the following commands to reset your .profile file back to default: (Replace all occurances of **yourusername** with your actual username)

```
cd /home/yourusername
mv .profile .profile.broken
cp /etc/skel/.profile ./
chown yourusername: .profile
```

Once done, test the change by running:

```
sudo -u yourusername -i
```

If that successfully gives you a bash prompt, the problem should be fixed. Run `exit`, then `shutdown -r now` to reboot the system.

Comment: Thank a lot for the solving. My precise work back. But i do it not trought safe mode. I do it when i'm in login page. Then press ctrl+alt+F1. Login with my username and password. The last, i do what you advice. May God bless u.

Comment: Ah, I got the impression you weren't able to log in even at the console due to that error.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, it is solved after I re-installed byobu. You can remove it use

```
sudo  byobu-launcher-uninstall
```

after you can login.