# Multiple problems with GRUB disk partitions Ubuntu login after update

Tags: grub2, partitioning, system-installation

Story:
I have some problems which began with the lost+found folder and space which I could not get rid of even after I did dd (from live sdcard) with complete zero overwrite to the whole disk and later shred with 3 random overwrites and 1 zero to the whole partition(the whole disk) except the hidden extra gigabytes the disk is 500gb (I have about 466gb and the rest 34gb are hidden) the folder lost+found is displayed as 0 items and empty by nautilus

Before I formatted the disk I tried to install ubuntu on one partition which was about 30gb and had used up space of about 600mb (as shown in gparted(screenshots I`ll provide in a while when I boot from livecd as guest can`t do anything)) it installed normally everything worked restarted loged in than updated as I copy pasted my previous home folder(pretty nice trick to save all your program settings when installing new system) than updated the os and restarted so updates could take place at the time I noticed grub was not displayed and directly booted ubuntu (on the previous restart I noticed that there`s an edge of about 5-10 px around the corners with the default colour and there`s a whole black box in the centre where grub gui should be)

after that I tried to log in but I was immediately kicked back to login screen  than I read about ctrl + alt + f2 gdm reconfigure and tried it with no result (when I log in from there a error message is displayed at the end of the lines "-bash: /usr/bin/byobu-launch no such file or directory" )(on the last restart it was the same)

In my opinion all of this is caused by lost+found and the unknown space as the whole thing started from it as I deleted empty lost+found folder Note: I never saw anything in these folders no mater how many times they were created later after I formatted the disk with dd I created ext2 part to see if they were gone but what I saw - 6gb of taken space and an empty lost+found

Questions:
1:how to remove lost+found along with the used up gigabytes from the disk
Note:When I was monitoring the shred process I noticed some processes with names migration/0 migration/1 ... with root permissions of them the migration/0 was active a lot and in a minute there were a lot of moments it reached 100% cpu usage and watching the system monitor graph at least 1 of the 2 cpus were at 100% almost 90% or so of the time (they were practically changing every 30 seconds or so from 100% to about 10-15%) else the other processes were shred with stable 5% and later 6%  firefox with no usage and an average of 8% and gnome-systemmonitor with max of 13% from time to time so at one point I started thinking this migration/0 is moving the megabytes during the format and later returning them back or not

2:how to repair grub(may repair itself after space of lost+found is free space again)?

3:how to be able to log in after software update

some technical info of my laptop if it will be of any use
Acer aspire 5732z
intel pentium dual core t4400 2.2ghz  3gb ram  gpu is intel chipset gma45
disk wd 500gb scorpio black bought about year and 4 months ago (29.03.2013)

I was thinking of trying creating live cd of a program with fancy name like dban that will just dd the disk and try it with no migration/0 process

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkf0A.png

Comment: I've had the exact same problem, and the advice to just "use the same username and password" doesn't work all the time. I had to copy basically all the files out and paste them inside the new installation under a different user. I think it might have to do with permissions, but I really think it is more of a bug

Comment: Do not mess with lost & found. It is created automatically and is needed if files have issues like chkdsk does in Windows. Space is another separate issue. Formatting drive uses space, creating journel uses space. Difference between hard drive decimal and binary sizes makes it seem space is lost but that is just how drive mfg sell drives.

Comment: I decided to ignore the 7GB distributed about evenly throughout my whole disk and wherever ext2,3,4 partition is created is created they show up ( I know the command )

Comment: I decided to ignore the 7GB distributed about evenly throughout my whole disk and wherever ext2,3,4 partition is created is created they show up ( I know the command ) so I began with byobu-launch and got to this question [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) tried everything from the first answer and also everything from here [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157395/ubuntu-12-04-cant-login-tty-console-said-bash-usr-bin-byobu-launch-no-suc) where the sudo -u yourusername -i command was displaying the error I got when logging and is not showing it

Comment: As for grub I found this
[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer)  and I still haven`t restarted to check if anything works

As for the partitions I made my data partition ntfs (with about 60mb used space not 5-6gb) and left 30gb ntfs for dual-boot with windows if I need it for any reason

I posted those comments if anybody needs them and sorry for the first comment didn`t know I have time limit for edit